# How to list all indexes of Mongo Collection with MongoDB Node native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Well I wanna know how I can fetch all indexes from a specific collection of mongodb.
I trying with `listIndexes`, `indexes` and `indexInformation`, but these methods only give me empty values(array and object), but if I execute `db.getCollection('truck').getIndexes()` on mongo terminal, this give me all indexes.

I think maybe this is a bug, but I don't find any information about this, so let me show my examples and a screenshot from "Robo 3T".

```js
await connection.collection('truck').indexes() // returns []
await connection.collection('truck').listIndexes().toArray() // returns []
await connection.collection('truck').indexInformation() // returns {}
```

[image]

So... Whats happend here? why these methods not working well?

Thanks :D

P.S: I'm using `mongodb` version `3.5.5`: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after try some solutions like move language from javascript to Python and using `Pymongo`... and getting the same result... I decided using command interface but usin the native api in driver...
Yep, I using `command`, let me show how:

```js
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb'
const client = await MongoClient.connect("...")
const db = client.db("MyOwnDatabase")

// the next line retrieve empty array
db.collection('truck').indexes();

// the next line retrieve all indexes 
db.command({listIndexes: "truck"}).cursor.firstBatch;
```

In Python is too similar:

```py
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient("...")
db = client.MyOwnDatabase

# retrieve empty object
db.truck.index_information()

# retrieve all indexes 
db.command("listIndexes", "truck")
```

I think this problem is about the driver... both are official driver, but none works well :D

> P.S: I know this question is about `javascript`, but I found the same problem in `Python` and this is the solution for both.

Comment: `db.truck.indexes();`. What is `truck`?

Comment: `truck` is the collection. I lost `collection(...)`

Answer (score 7):

Looks like in the code `await connection.collection('truck').indexes()` you need to specify the database also. It is not clear what is `connection`.

The following script will print the indexes in the specified database and collection.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

( async function() {
     const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true } );
     try {
        await client.connect();
        const coll = client.db('test').collection('books');
        const indxs = await coll.indexes();
        console.log(indxs);     // prints all the indexes
     } catch (err) {
         console.log(err.stack);
     }
     client.close();
)();
```

Comment: But I specified the database... The problem is not about db :'(

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is the driver cos' I try the same with python and nodejs but... this not work. After try another thinks I found the solution: using `command`. Show my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

`listIndexes` is a database command, you have to call it like this:

```
db.runCommand( {listIndexes: "truck"} )
```

or using the shorthand

```
db.truck.getIndexes()
db.collection('truck').getIndexes()
```

Method `indexInformation` does not exist in MongoDB (at least I did not find it). `collection.indexes()` I did not find either.

Comment: Well I think you may need read the question and my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

...for prettier output:

```
for ( var i=0; i < indxs.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(indxs[i].ns + '.' + indxs[i].name,'key(s):-\n',indxs[i].key);
}
```

Comment: A full example is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

##### Working Example in Nodejs with `indexes()`

a) Definition

```
export function getIndexes(coll, callback: Function) {
MongoClient.connect(process.env.uri, (err, db) => {
    db.db(dbWeb).collection(coll).indexes( (err, res) => {
        callback(res)
        db.close();
    })
})
```

}

b) Call

```
export function getIndexes(coll) { mongo[arguments.callee.name](coll, res => { console.log(res) }) }
```